# What is the covariance matrix of a fixed matrix multiplied by a vector of random variables?

Tags: covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a random variable $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then we know that if a constant, say $a$, is multiplied by $\epsilon$, then

\begin{equation}
a\epsilon\sim N\left(0,a^2\sigma^2\right)
\end{equation}

Now suppose $w$ is an $n\times 1$ vector of random variables, such that

\begin{equation}
w\sim N\left(0,\Omega\right)
\end{equation}
and suppose, now we have the $n\times p$ matrix of constants $A$. What would then be

\begin{equation}
A'w\sim N\left(0,?\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: if the original covariance matrix of $w$ has dimensions $n \times n$, and if the covariance matrix of $A'w$ has dimensions $p \times p$, then what matrices would you need to left-multiply and right-multiply the original covariance matrix by to obtain a covariance matrix with dimensions $p \times p$? You are essentially performing a change of basis on the original covariance matrix.

Comment: @mhdadk I did think about the dimensions and did consider $A'\Omega A$, but was not sure. Thanks for confirming this.